# How to design step progress bar using jquery,css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I spent 3 days. I tried to design step by step progress bar like below.

====(discount 10 %)======(discount 20 %)=====(discount 30 %)========

fill it dynamically how can i do that i searched on google every thing i tried to customize but not success so far.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code so far please.

Comment: How about this: https://jqueryui.com/progressbar

Comment: You mean something like this or: <===10%===                             >, <===========100%===========>?

Answer (score 1):

I've just made this to inspire you (not sure if it's what you try to do).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#discount').on('change', function() {
  $('#discount-bar').css({'width' : $(this).val() + '%'});
 });
});
```

```css
select {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.discount-bar-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.discount-bar-container .discount-bar {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: width 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="discount">Choose a value :</label>
<select name="discount" id="discount">
 <option value="0">0%</option>
 <option value="10">10%</option>
 <option value="20">20%</option>
 <option value="30">30%</option>
 <option value="40">40%</option>
 <option value="50">50%</option>
 <option value="60">60%</option>
 <option value="70">70%</option>
 <option value="80">80%</option>
 <option value="90">90%</option>
 <option value="100">100%</option>
</select>

<div class="discount-bar-container">
 <div class="discount-bar" id="discount-bar"></div>
</div>
```